# Passing template prototype as template argument - is it possible?

Tags: c++, templates

So first, apologies for terminology - I'm not sure if template prototype is the correct term. By this I mean :

```
template <class T, class X>
class TemplatePrototype
{
 // code
};
```

I have a situation where I have a function that creates a template object based upon template arguments to that function.

```
template <class T, class X>
void doSomething()
{
    TemplatePrototype<T, X> aTemplateTX;
    aTemplateTX.doSomethingElse();
}
```

However, there are about 15 different versions of TemplatePrototype, which all have the same interface but different execution (TemplatePrototype is provided by another library). As a result, I have a lot of code that looks like this:

```
template <class T, class X>
void doSomethingWithOne()
{
    TemplatePrototypeOne<T, X> aTemplateTX;
    aTemplateTX.doSomethingElse();
}

template <class T, class X>
void doSomethingWithTwo()
{
    TemplatePrototypeTwo<T, X> aTemplateTX;
    aTemplateTX.doSomethingElse();
}
```

As a consequence of the architecture, I *must* know which TemplatePrototype I am going to use *before* I know the actual types T and X. I would *like* to see something like this:

```
template <class T, class X, class Prototype>
void doSomething()
{
    Prototype<T, X> aPrototype;
    aPrototype.doSomething();
}
```

But where I have *specified part of the template arguments in advance* - i.e I specify Prototype before I know T and X. Obviously, this is not possible in C++.

Equally, I cannot pass the Prototype as a template argument because it will still result in huge amounts of duplicate code.

Some important facts : I know the range of all possible inputs.

So I could theoretically use a macro to define each possible template specialisation and insert them into a container, which I would then use to access the specialisation I need. However, I am looking for a more 'elegant' solution - is it possible to pass template prototypes without specialising them as an argument to a template class, and then instantiate later when a function is called? Example:

```
template <class Prototype>
class Holder
{
    template <class T, class X>
    void doSomething()
    {
        Prototype<T, X> aPrototype;
        aPrototype.doSomethingElse();
    }
};
```

As far as I know this is impossible, but I was wondering if the SO community had some folks who know a solution?

EDIT:

So I have implemented this as my solution, thanks to the answers below!

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
        Foo() { aPtr = 0; }
        T* aPtr;
};

template <template<typename> class C>
struct Bar
{
        template <class T>
        void doSomething()
        {
                C<T> aClass;
                if (aClass.aPtr)
                        std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
        }
};


int main()
{
        Bar<Foo> aFoo;
        aFoo.doSomething<int>();

        return 0;
}
```

This enables me to specify which TemplatePrototype I wish to use, *before* I can know the template parameters.

Comment: There is such thing as template template parameters: one can write `template<template<class, class> class Prototype> ... { Prototype<T1, T2> ... }`

Comment: Note, `template` `template` parameters seem very handy until you actually try to use them in a nontrivial fashion. Then you start running into problems caused by the facts that (1) the number of template parameters to the template is fixed, and (2) the class type is now completely fixed as well. Feel free to give them a try, but be aware that you may need to end up finding a different solution.

Comment: @Mehrdad No, their count isn't fixed. There are variadic template template parameters ;) See my updated answer.

Comment: @leemes: Oh I see, my bad! Deleting my last comment. Learned something new today, thanks. :) However, it seems to me that this only solves the problem for the case when all the template parameters are classes. It still doesn't allow for other parameter types. (I'm imagining a use case such as `template<class T, template<class> class Alloc> class container { ... }`, where the user wants to pass an allocator such as `template<class T, size_t N> struct stack_allocator { T local_buf[N]; ... }` but cannot.

Comment: @Mehrdad You're right, that only works for template template parameters whose template parameters are types (that starts to sound really strange now...). I don't know of a way to handle all kinds of parameters, I guess there is none. If I were to use such an interface in my codebase, I'd add overloads as needed...

Comment: @leemes: what do you mean by overloads? There are an infinite number of possibilities here

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes. That's why I'd add them *as needed*. With that I mean, as soon as I see the need for `<class,int>`, I add one for `<class,int>`-kind of template types, but not for every combination (which is impossible).

Comment: @leemes what I mean is that you can't predict what the user might give you... That's the whole point of using variable functions instead of arbitrarily long overloads. That's why template templates are fragile - they only work in restricted cases.

Comment: @Mehrdad But they are less restrictive than when *not* using them... You can't cover all cases. But they can cover all `class...`-cases. If you need to cover more cases, add overloads, it's the only option. And when I said I "add as needed", I mean the case where the user of this function is also the writer of this function, i.e. I assumed we're not talking about writing a multi-purpose library (like boost for example) but the actual code base of a program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use a template template parameter, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
};

template <template<typename> class C>
struct Bar
{
};
```

then

```
Bar<Foo> b;
```

Comment: Many thanks - this solved my exact issue in throwaway, now to implement it for the production code. Greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for **template template parameters**.

In the template parameter list, instead of just:

```
class TemplatePrototype
```

specify your prototype as a class template which itself has two template type parameters (without giving them a name here), like:

```
template<class,class> class TemplatePrototype
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will result in a function like:

```
template <class T, class X,
          template<class,class> class TemplatePrototype>
void doSomething()
{
    TemplatePrototype<T, X> aTemplateTX;
    aTemplateTX.doSomethingElse();
}
```

Invocation example:

```
doSomething<T, X, TemplatePrototypeOne>();
```

---

To become independent of the number of template parameters you pass to your "prototype" (here it was 2, namely `T` and `X`), you can use variadic templates (since C++11).

For this, first move the prototype template parameter to the first position:

```
template <template<class,class> class TemplatePrototype,
          class T, class X>
```

Then, replace `class T, class X` with `class ...Ts`, which is a placeholder of an arbitrary number of type parameters. Also, in the template template parameter list, replace `class,class` with `class...`. And in the instantiation within the function implementation, replace `<T, X>` with `<Ts...>` to "expand" the parameter pack.

The result then looks like this:

```
template <template<class...> class TemplatePrototype,
          class ... Ts>
void doSomething()
{
    TemplatePrototype<Ts...> aTemplateTs;
    aTemplateTs.doSomethingElse();
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://ideone.com/GhGwMw)

Comment: Thank you - this has taught me a significant amount! I would like to accept both answers as correct if I could! Nim's answer more directly answered my specific question, but I feel bad that I can't also accept this because you've definitely given me a lot more information!